# Modelling Post and Flag relationship in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, data-modeling

I am modeling the data for my web I am building. I use Postgresql database.

In the app there are posts like SO posts and also the flags for posts as Github flags or marks, whatever the correct term for it. A post can have only one flag at a time. There are plenty of posts ever increasing, but four or five flags and they will not increase.

**First approach**, **normalized**; I have modeled this part of my data with three tables; two for the corresponding entities posts and flags, and one for the relationship as post_flag. No reference in any of the entity tables mentioned to the other entity table for relationship. All relationship is recorded in the relationship table post_flag, and that is only the id pair for ids of a post and a flag.

Table structure in that case would be:

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    title character varying(100),
    text text,
    score integer DEFAULT 0,
    author_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
    product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products (id),
);

CREATE TABLE flags
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    flag character varying(30) NOT NULL -- planned, in progress, fixed
);

CREATE TABLE post_flag
(
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    post_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES posts (id),
    flag_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES flags (id)
);
```

To get posts flagged as fixed I have to use:

```
-- homepage posts- fixed posts tab
SELECT
    p.*,
    f.flag
FROM posts p

JOIN post_flag p_f
ON p.id = p_f.post_id
JOIN flags f
ON p_f.flag_id = f.id

WHERE f.flag = 'fixed'
ORDER BY p_f.created_at DESC
```

**Second approach**; I have two tables posts and flags. The table posts has a flag_id column that references a flag in the flags table.

```
CREATE TABLE posts
    (
        id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
        created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        title character varying(100),
        text text,
        score integer DEFAULT 0,
        author_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
        product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products (id),
        flag_id integer DEFAULT NULL REFERENCES flags (id)
    );

    CREATE TABLE flags
    (
        id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
        created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
        flag character varying(30) NOT NULL -- one of planned, in progress, fixed
    );
```

For same data;

```
-- homepage posts- fixed posts tab
SELECT
    p.*,
    f.flag
FROM posts p

JOIN flags f
ON p.flag_id = f.id

WHERE f.flag = 'fixed'
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
```

**Third approach**  **denormalized**; I have only one table posts. Posts table has a flag column to store the flag assigned to the post.

```
CREATE TABLE posts
        (
            id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
            created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            title character varying(100),
            text text,
            score integer DEFAULT 0,
            author_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES users (id),
            product_id integer NOT NULL REFERENCES products (id),
            flag character varying(30)
        );
```

Here I would only have for same data;

```
-- homepage posts- fixed posts tab
SELECT
    p.*,
FROM posts p

WHERE p.flag = 'fixed'
ORDER BY p.created_at DESC
```

I wonder if first approach is an overkill in terms of normalization of data in a RDBMS like Postgresql? For a post comment relationship that first approach would be great and indeed I make use of it. But I have some very few quantity data used as meta data for posts as badges, flags, tags. As you see in fact in the most normal form, the first approach, I already use some product_id etc for a using one less `JOIN` but to another table as a different relation, not to the flags. So, there my approach fits into my second approach. Should I use the more denormalized approach, the third one, having posts table and a flag column in it? What is the better approach in terms of performance, expansion, and maintainability?

Comment: It may just be me, but seeing your different table structures would be more beneficial than seeing the queries you're using against them in evaluating the degree of normalization and it's effects.

Comment: Added the data structures.

Answer (score 1):

Use the second approach.

The first is a many-to-many data structure and you say

> A post can have only one flag at a time.

So you would then have to build the business logic in to the front-end or set up complex rules to check a post never have more than one flag.

The third approach will result in messy data, again unless you implement checks or rules to ensure the flags are not misspelled or new ones added.

Expansion and maintainability are provided in the second approach; it is also self documenting. Worry about performance when it *actually becomes* a problem, and not before.

Personally I would make the `flag_id` field in the `posts` table `NULL`, which would allow you to model a post without a flag.

**Blending two approaches**

Assuming your flag names are unique, you can use the flag name as a natural key. Your table structures would then be

```
CREATE TABLE posts
(
    id bigserial PRIMARY KEY,
    ... other fields
    flag character varying(30) REFERENCES flags (flag)
);

CREATE TABLE flags
(
    flag character varying(30) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

You then get the benefit of being able to write queries for flag *without* having to `JOIN` to the `flags` table while having flag names checked by the table reference.

Comment: Is your answer still same for the part before the 'blending two approaches'  part if I have post_id unique in the post_flag table, So updates to flag of a post are made there and made only there, without inserting a new row for a post. Actually the first one seems to have the history of changes capability if I have another id column for as PK, and this makes it many-to-many. If I need only one flag for one post and also history can select the latest timestamp'ed one with `WHERE` clause, as well.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you could make `post_id` the primary key to enforce uniqueness. Then, yes, updates to the flag would only change the `post_flag` table. But that sounds to me like a premature performance optimisation. Do you have a problem with quickly updating a poset flag? (I wrote this comment before you edited yours)

Comment: Using the many-to-many approach would give you a history  of the flags for a post, which can be useful. Do you need it? If so, then the creation date of the `post_flag` row could be automatically set and then used to get the current flag.

Comment: I may need it, but not now. if this does not cause any other drawbacks I a can implement it this as it at the beginning now. I want to have a consistent and quickly repeatable and not bad performance pattern in development.

Comment: Also this way, first approach, I can have easy update code in server side. I did not mean to have one update, update in place, for performance. Just for easy and readable coding

Comment: Use the approach that satisfies the need _now_, not what you _might_ need in the future - google "developer gold plating" or read the [Coding Horror](https://blog.codinghorror.com/gold-plating/) post on it. If you don't need the flag change history don't implement it.

Comment: The blending two  approaches seems better than the second approach. omitting the `JOIN` and updates are equivalently easy.